# Coincidencias en expresion regular

Tags: php, regex

estoy intentando separar un string con una expresion regular pero no encuentro la forma de traer solo el string hasta encontrar un `espacio letra espacio`

estos son los string que estoy intentando separar:

```
T-HERR 1/2 ARGO Z A:14.7 B:20mm LP*SAT+BAR BTEL03928
T-REMA LS L D:9.7mm OXE Z00800
```

y esta es la expresion regular que estoy usando:

```
/(^[A-Z{1,2}]-[A-Z]*)(\s[A-Z0-9{\/\s}]*)/gm
```

Estoy buscando que  string de arriba queden separados de esta forma:

`T-HERR`  `1/2 ARGO` `Z` `A:14.7 B:20mm` LP*SAT+BAR BTEL03928

`T-REMA`  `LS` `L` `D:9.7mm` OXE Z00800

solo me interesa los campos en gris, lo demas es irrelevante pero como se puede observar entre el primer y segundo ejemplo el segundo grupo (`1/2 ARGO` y `LS`) uno tiene un `/` y `espacios` y el otro no.

Comment: Disculpe por la pregunta un poco mal formulada lo que quiero saber es como, en una expresion regular coger todo un string hasta encontrar un espacio seguido de una letra mas un espacio algo como ` A ` es eso posible ?

Comment: no funciona por que si separo por espacios por ejemplo 1/2 ARGO y LS  no me va na quedar en el mismo grupo

Comment: Me parece que hay un patron en las cadenas, algo como `[ITEM] [MODELO] [UNA-LETRA] [MEDIDA] [ALGO]`, ¿pude ser?

Comment: siiii ese es el patron pero en `[MODELO]` pueden haber espacios o un string completo como por ejemplo  `1/2 ARGO` y `LS`

Answer (score 1):

Logre solucionar mi problema con la siguiente expresion regular

```
/^([A-Z])-([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((?:\S+\s*)+)\s+(.+)$/
```

```
$strings = [
    "T-HERR 1/2 ARGO Z A:14.7 B:20mm LP*SAT+BAR BTEL03928",
    "M-REMA LS L D:9.7mm OXE Z00800",
    "C-OJA RED 5/16 L D:14 L:4.5 P:8mm CA-118*LAS+BAR BTEL03933"
];

$pattern = '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((?:\S+\s*)+)\s+(.+)$/';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
        $result = array_slice($matches, 1);
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

obteniendo como resultado

```
Array
(
    [0] => T
    [1] => HERR
    [2] => 1/2 ARGO
    [3] => Z
    [4] => A:14.7 B:20mm
    [5] => LP*SAT+BAR BTEL03928
)
Array
(
    [0] => M
    [1] => REMA
    [2] => LS
    [3] => L
    [4] => D:9.7mm
    [5] => OXE Z00800
)
Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => OJA
    [2] => RED 5/16
    [3] => L
    [4] => D:14 L:4.5 P:8mm
    [5] => CA-118*LAS+BAR BTEL03933
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurrio esta RegEx:

```
/^([a-z\-]+) (.+) ([a-z]) ((?:\w:\S+ ?)+) (.+)$/i
```

Si la aplicamos usando PHP, quedaría:

```php
$strings = [
    "T-HERR 1/2 ARGO Z A:14.7 B:20mm LP*SAT+BAR BTEL03928",
    "M-REMA LS L D:9.7mm OXE Z00800",
    "C-OJA RED 5/16 L D:14 L:4.5 P:8mm CA-118*LAS+BAR BTEL03933"
];
$pattern = '/^([a-z\-]+) (.+) ([a-z]) ((?:\w:\S+ ?)+) (.+)$/i';
$matches = [];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
        $result = array_slice($matches, 1);
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

Y el resutaldo sería:

```
Array
(
    [0] => T-HERR
    [1] => 1/2 ARGO
    [2] => Z
    [3] => A:14.7 B:20mm
    [4] => LP*SAT+BAR BTEL03928
)
Array
(
    [0] => M-REMA
    [1] => LS
    [2] => L
    [3] => D:9.7mm
    [4] => OXE Z00800
)
Array
(
    [0] => C-OJA
    [1] => RED 5/16
    [2] => L
    [3] => D:14 L:4.5 P:8mm
    [4] => CA-118*LAS+BAR BTEL03933
)
```